# Subjonctif ou indicatif après "non parce que"

Tags: grammaire, négation, conjonctions, subjonctif, indicatif

Est-ce qu'on emploie le subjonctif ou l'indicatif après "non parce que" ?

Ex.

> Je n'ai pas lu ce livre, non parce que je suis paresseux, mais parce
>   que je n'avais pas le temps.

ou

> Je n'ai pas lu ce livre, non parce que je sois paresseux, mais parce
>   que je n'avais pas le temps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si la personne qui parle est paresseuse et qu'elle tient à affirmer cela elle utilise le présent ;

- Je n'ai pas lu ce livre, non parce que je suis paresseux, mais parce que je n'avais pas le temps.

Autrement le subjonctif ne peut pas être utilisé mais je ne sais pas pourquoi ; si l'on veut indiquer un état de chose hypothétique (que l'on soit paresseux ou non) on utilise couramment le conditionnel ;

- Je n'ai pas lu ce livre, non parce que je serais paresseux, mais parce que je n'avais pas le temps.

Une tournure avec laquelle le subjonctif est correct est la suivante ;

- Je n'ai pas lu ce livre, non que je sois paresseux, mais parce que je n'avais pas le temps.

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a jamais de subjonctif après **parce que**.

**Parce que** exprime une cause, un fait qui a généré une conséquence. En français, pour décrire un constat ou un fait, on utilise l'indicatif.